# Is eclipse.ini used for Java apps I compile and start from Eclipse or for the IDE itself?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

I read the articles on the following web sites but don't yet have a clear picture of the purpose of `eclipse.ini`:

- https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F,
- https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

My question is in the title.

Comment: They are for the the IDE proper.  The equivalent settings for applications started from eclipse are controlled through run configurations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eclipse.ini file is just for Eclipse itself.

For Java programs you run from Eclipse the configuration is in the 'Run > Run Configurations' dialog.